# Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead struct error

Tags: arrays, json, swift, decode

Here is my JSON

```
{"states":\[{"name":"Alabama","nickname":"Cotton State"},{"name":"Alaska","nickname":"The Last Frontier"},{"name":"Arizona","nickname":"The Grand Canyon State"},{"name":"Arkansas","nickname":"Natural State"},{"name":"California","nickname":"Golden State"},{"name":"Connectict","nickname":"Nutmeg State"},{"name":"Delaware","nickname":"First State"},{"name":"Florida","nickname":"Sunshine State"},{"name":"Georgia","nickname":"Peach State"},{"name":"Hawaii","nickname":"Aloha State"},{"name":"Idaho","nickname":"Gem State"},{"name":"Illinois","nickname":"Prairie State"},{"name":"Colorado","nickname":"Centennial State"},{"name":"Indiana","nickname":"Hoosier State"},{"name":"Iowa","nickname":"Hawkeye State"},{"name":"Kansas","nickname":"Sunflower State"},{"name":"Kentucky","nickname":"Bluegrass State"},{"name":"Louisiana","nickname":"Pelican State"},{"name":"Maine","nickname":"Pine Tree State"},{"name":"Maryland","nickname":"Free State"},{"name":"Massachusetts","nickname":"Bay State"},{"name":"Michigan","nickname":"Great Lake State"},{"name":"Minnesota","nickname":"Land of 10,000 Lakes"},{"name":"Mississippi","nickname":"Magnolia"},{"name":"Missouri","nickname":"Show Me States"},{"name":"Montana","nickname":"Treasure State"},{"name":"Nebraska","nickname":"Cornhusker State"},{"name":"Nevada","nickname":"Silver State"},{"name":"New Hampshire","nickname":"Granite State"},{"name":"New Jersey","nickname":"Garden State"},{"name":"New Mexico","nickname":"Land of Enchantment"},{"name":"New York","nickname":"Empire State"},{"name":"North Carolina","nickname":"Tar Heel State"},{"name":"North Dakota","nickname":"Flickertail State"},{"name":"Ohio","nickname":"Buckeye State"},{"name":"Oklahoma","nickname":"Sooner State"},{"name":"Oregon","nickname":"Beaver State"},{"name":"Pennsylvania","nickname":"Keystone State"},{"name":"Rhode Island","nickname":"Little Rhody"},{"name":"South Carolina","nickname":"Palmetto State"},{"name":"South Dakota","nickname":"Mount Rushmore State"},{"name":"Tennessee","nickname":"Volunteer State"},{"name":"Texas","nickname":"Lone Star State"},{"name":"Utah","nickname":"Beehive State"},{"name":"Vermont","nickname":"Green Mountain State"},{"name":"Virginia","nickname":"Old Dominion State"},{"name":"Washington","nickname":"Evergreen State"},{"name":"West Virginia","nickname":"Mountain State"},{"name":"Wisconsin","nickname":"Badger State"},{"name":"Wyoming","nickname":"Equality State"}\]}
```

Here is the relevant pieces of code

```
struct database: Decodable{
var states: Array\<String\>

        }
```

The above is the structure part I have for the data. Below is the actual decoding bit of the code.

```
do{
let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([database].self,from: data)
print(json)
} catch let error as NSError {
print("Error serializing JSON Data: \(error)")
}
```

My exact error message is below.

**Error serializing JSON Data: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))**

I'm trying to just extract the above JSON object into something I can print out, in the print statement below. Eventually I'll be doing other stuff with it, but for now I just want to be able to successfully decode the object at all.

I've tried messing around with removing the brackets around [database] inside of the decode statement. I've also tried a different declaration of the database struct, that looked kind of like the snippet below, but that didn't work either. It's almost definitely me declaring the struct database part wrong, but knowing what the issue might be unfortunately hasn't got me a lot closer to fixing it.

```
var states: [States]

struct States: Decodeable{
let name: String
let nickname: String}
```

Comment: Paste your JSON into [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) and compare the models it generates to yours.

Comment: Pasting it into there, I think I've (mostly) solved it. I needed to get rid of the brackets around my decoding statement and do the second option I posted in the part that says what I tried. Thought I had done that, but I guess I somehow missed the combination. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get rid of the brackets around my decoding statement, and use my secondary method I'd tried to make for the structure.

```
struct database: Decodable{
        var states: [State]
        
    }
    struct State: Decodable{
        let name,nickname: String
    }
```

---

```
do{
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(database.self,from: data)
            print(json)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error serializing JSON Data: \(error)")
        }
```

Comment: You should consider adopting the standard Swift capitalization practices -- in this case, that means capitalizing type names. So, `database` should be `Database`